# Why do fixed-width integers print out chars instead of ints?

Tags: c++, integer, fixed-width

Given the following code.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int8_t x = 5;
    std::cout << x << '\n';

    int y = 5;
    std::cout << y;

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

My output is a *three-leaf clover* and *5*. If fixed-width integers are integers, why are they outputting their number's ASCII character symbol?

Edit: just found out this behavior only happens for 8-bit fixed-width integers? Is this compiler behavior?

Comment: `std::is_same<std::int8_t, signed char>::value`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, they are integers in the sense that you can do 8 bit integer arithmetic with them.

But apparently on your system, `int8_t` is implemented as a `typedef` to `signed char`. This is completely legal since `signed char`s are also integers, but gives unexpected results since the `operator<<` for `signed char`s prints their character symbol and not their numeric value. Anything else would just be weird if someone tried to print an `signed char`.

If you want to see the numeric value of your `int8_t`, just cast to `int` before printing.

Comment: thanks for the answer. That was a tricky thing they did with `int8_t`.

Comment: I wish opaque typedefs exists... :(

Answer (score 2):

The (optional) fixed-width types `intN_t`, and also various other types like `uint_fast16_t`, `uintmax_t` and `intptr_t`, are *aliases* for one of the built-in integral types. You don't know what the actual types they're aliasing are, only that they must meet the documented constraints.

In the case of "exactly 8 bits", the constraints don't leave much room, though, and the only integral types that can be 8 bits wide are the `char` types (recall there are three of them). So `int8_t`, if it exists, must be an alias for either `char` or `signed char`.

Unrelatedly, iostreams defines overloads for `operator<<` for the all character types which have the effect of writing the value directly to the output rather than formatting the integer as a decimal string (this is so that you can conveniently write `std::cout << 'a'`), and this overload is also used for `int8_t` -- overload resolution works on types, not on type names. (It is perhaps regrettable that there is an [special ostream overload for `signed char`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2); it might have been nicer to *only* provide the overload for `char` and treat the other types like ordinary integers.) That's why you see the value printed as a character in your system's encoding.

If you want to print the value formatted as a string, just convert it to one of the wider integral types. For example, you can apply the standard promotions with the unary plus: `int8_t x = 5; std::cout << +x;`

Comment: Must they really be aliases for the "built-in" integral types?

Comment: @MSalters: Yes. The relevant wording is in the C standard, from which this library component is imported. The term "signed integer type" is a term of art, defined in "Language/Concepts/Types".

Comment: @Kerrek SB I never heard of using +x to change a char to an integer in the output. I thought it was just a redundant unary operator which explicitly stated a value was positive?

Comment: @WanderingIdiot: The C++ type system is bewilderingly complex. [Default promotions and arithmetic conversions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n) are not to be taken lightly :-S

Comment: @WanderingIdiot the arithmetic operators all promote any integral type narrower than `int` to `int` before operating.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Or `unsigned int`, depending on the weather.

Comment: @KerrekSB by "narrower" I meant being of fewer (value) bits . Promotion to `unsigned int` only happens if the signed type was the same width but lower rank.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I see, yes. But then your statement was incomplete, since integral types that are not narrower may also be promoted (e.g. `signed char` and `short int` may have the same width as `int`, but are still promoted).